# Webdriver how to fetch updated HTML post AJAX event?

Tags: java, dom, selenium, webdriver, automated-tests

I need to evaluate DOM tree during automated testing.

Initially on opening of link the web application is  loading 100 records. On Click() event after an AJAX request its loading 400 more records.

```
 WebDriver obj = new FirefoxDriver();
 obj.get("https://localhost/WebApplication");
 WebElement loadAllLinkEle = obj.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[class=load-all]"));
 loadAllLinkEle.click();
 Document doc = Jsoup.parse(obj.getPageSource(), "UTF-8");
 System.out.println(doc.html());
```

When I am trying to print the document, its printing OLD html, the html that was loaded before the Click event called.

How to get the updated DOM tree?

Comment: I think the DOM is just not updated when you parse it. Try to [wait till the Ajax call is finished](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)

Comment: But can I call this method after  my click event?

Comment: Sure! Why not? Try it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following solution worked.

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}

WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(obj, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("container")));;
```

Comment: why Thread.sleep? What are you sleeping for if WebDriverWait is pooling for an element with id=container? Increase webdriverwait timeout if thats not enough, but do not sleep. The whole point of webdriverwait is to exactly avoid such sleeps which are really brittle. You never know if the sleep is sufficient enough, it could be less or it could be more.

Comment: The solution was very much specific to my requirement. My page was not containing much IDs.Atleast after AJAX call, no NEW IDs were getting added. So I did this workaround.Container is the ID that gets loaded on first loading of page.

Comment: ok, then the webdriverwait in your solution is not necessarily solving your problem. And Therefore this solution is flawed. Do you know for sure that 400 rows are inserted when you click on the button? Alternatively you could also use internal java script.

Comment: Disclaimer:- I am new to Automated testing. 
Yes I am sure that new data will come. so as you now my requirement then can you please suggest the standard solution please. Only one restriction, we can not add any test JS script in Application. We are looking to do this automated without touching   codebase. I would be more than happy to learn.

Comment: Sure. Do you know the exact count of rows which will be added when you click? Also its totally fine to use internal hooks from developers when dealing with situations like these. Browser simulation is a hard problem to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*"));
String code = element.getAttribute("outerHTML");
```